# NVIDIA Driver Installation Issue

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, dependencies

Completely new to Linux took me a while to get everything setup the way I want it to, well not everything obviously. I'm attempting to install a new NVIDIA driver and it's not allowing me. I'm getting this message. I've searched far and wide and found several people had the same problem but none of their solutions helped me. I tried fixing packages with Synaptic and the terminal but nothing's working.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-418 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please excuse my lack of knowledge if this is something of an easy fix, or something that I might just be overlooking. I'm like 2 days new and everything I've been doing has been with Google.

Comment: try out this https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/